# interesting remainder problem

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry

Let $A=\left( 2\sin{\dfrac{7\pi}{18}}+1 \right)^{2556}$.

How can one find the remainder from the division of $\lfloor A \rfloor$  by $17$ ?

I have no idea. Thank you.

Comment: first you can reduce the exponent, $6 \equiv 2556 \mod 17$

Comment: Why? The floor comes after the exponent.  You are raising an irrational number to a power.

Comment: Have you tried using [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula) and the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) ?

Comment: @Michael...yes, that's indeed true! (should have given it a second thought)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2\sin7\pi/18+1=2\cos\pi/9+1\\
B(n)=(1+2\cos\pi/9)^n+(1+2\cos5\pi/9)^n+(1+2\cos7\pi/9)^n\in\mathbb{Z}$$
Try to find the remainders modulo $17$, and do they repeat?
Can you find a recursion for $B(n)$?  Hint: the three bases in $B(n)$ are the roots of $x^3-3x^2+1=0$

Comment: Thank you. Now I get a solution

Comment: @Bless, Would you mind sharing the solution?